# Iterating over arrays to create vectors: Python Vs MATLAB

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, loops

So I have this code in MATLAB:

```
dx = 1E-2;
u = [0:0.01:1000]%g(:,4); 
minu= min(u);
maxu = max(u);
du = dx*1.5; % change back 

p1 = floor((maxu-minu)/du)+1;
N1 = zeros(p1,1);

    for i = 1:size(u,1)
     U1 = floor((u(i)-minu)/du) + 1; %seems to either only be 0 or 1?? 
     N1(U1) = N1(U1)+1;
    end

L = (N1/(p1*du)); 

plot(tan(L))
grid on
```

Which produces

[image: plot]

I tried to transfer this over to Python with:

```
# %%
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import cmath
from scipy.fft import fft
from scipy.fft import ifft
# import sympy as sy
# import sympy.abc as spa
# from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d


dx = 1E-2;
u = np.arange(0, 1000, 0.1)
minu= min(u);
maxu = max(u);
du = dx*1.5

p1 = np.floor((maxu-minu)/du)+1;
N1 = np.zeros((int(p1), 1))

for i in range(1, len((u))):
    U1 = np.floor( (u - minu) / du ) + 1
    N1[U1] = N1[U1]+1

L = (N1/(p1*du)); 

plt.plot(np.tan(L))
```

But it fails at the line `N1[U1] = N1[U1]+1` because I'm not familiar with the syntax in Python, how might one replicate the line `N1(U1) = N1(U1)+1;` in Python?

I appreciate that this is a basic question to ask but I'm a newcommer to the language.

Comment: Okay so from what I can see here you're trying to create a vector in a for loop as in

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/321309-create-vector-for-data-after-each-iteration-of-a-for-loop

Yes?

Comment: Hi there. Instead of posting MATLAB code and asking how to translate it to Python, why not explain at a higher level what you actually want to accomplish? Right off the bat seeing a for-loop to create numpy objects makes me suspicious that you're not doing it in the most efficient way.

Comment: Okay so as @Roberto_1986 pointed out, what I want to do is append the results of u into the array of zeros by iterating across it in the for loop. linked page. Essentially I want to take N1 and loop over it to create a new vector using the for loop

Comment: MATLAB indexing starts at 1, Python indexing starts at 0. In MATLAB you have `U1 = … + 1`. Leave out the +1 in Python.

Comment: what is the failure? error message?

Answer (score 0):

I should have just voted to close, since you did not provide any debugging details.  But since I'm such a nice condescending guy :)

In `ipython` with `np` imported:

```
In [1]: dx = 1E-2;
   ...: u = np.arange(0, 1000, 0.1)
   ...: minu= min(u);
   ...: maxu = max(u);
   ...: du = dx*1.5
   ...: 
   ...: p1 = np.floor((maxu-minu)/du)+1;
   ...: N1 = np.zeros((int(p1), 1))
   ...:
```

Let's check what this code as has produced:

```
In [2]: N1.shape
Out[2]: (66661, 1)
In [3]: u.shape
Out[3]: (10000,)
```

Now the loop that has some sort of error, which you forgot to show (or did you omit it just to make us work?):

```
In [4]: for i in range(1, len((u))):
   ...:     U1 = np.floor( (u - minu) / du ) + 1
   ...:     N1[U1] = N1[U1]+1
   ...: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [4] in <cell line: 1>
    N1[U1] = N1[U1]+1
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

What's this `U1` index?

```
In [5]: U1.shape
Out[5]: (10000,)
In [6]: U1.dtype
Out[6]: dtype('float64')
In [7]: U1[:10]
Out[7]: array([ 1.,  7., 14., 21., 27., 34., 41., 47., 54., 61.])
```

It's a large list of floats.  Floats cannot be used as indexes!  OK, they are integer values, but they are still floats - see the decimal point.  `floor` does truncate floats, but it still leaves them as floats.

`U1` has the size of `u`, but for some reason you iterate over its length.  Why didn't you use `i`, the iteration variable?

Look at what the `U1` calc is trying to do - without the floor:

```
In [10]: u[:10]
Out[10]: array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9])
In [11]: (u[:10]-minu)/du
Out[11]: 
array([ 0.        ,  6.66666667, 13.33333333, 20.        , 26.66666667,
       33.33333333, 40.        , 46.66666667, 53.33333333, 60.        ])
In [12]: (u[:10]-minu)/du+1
Out[12]: 
array([ 1.        ,  7.66666667, 14.33333333, 21.        , 27.66666667,
       34.33333333, 41.        , 47.66666667, 54.33333333, 61.        ])
```

Those don't make much sense as index values.

I may test the MATLAB code (in Octave), to see what you are trying to replicate.  But for now I'll let you stew in your own juices :)

When translating MATLAB to python/numpy, I find it best to run the codes side by side in interactive sessions.  That way I can verify that both are producing the same thing.  An alternative is to thoroughly digest what the MATLAB is doing, and replicate that from scratch in python, without trying to do a line by line copy; but sometimes that's more work.

## Octave

What's with this `%g...` bit?  modulus or comment?  I was puzzled by the long display of the `u` variable.

```
u = [0:0.01:1000]%g(:,4);
```

correcting that:

```
>> u = [0:0.01:1000];
>> minu= min(u);
>> maxu = max(u);
>> du = dx*1.5; % change back
>>
>> p1 = floor((maxu-minu)/du)+1;
>> N1 = zeros(p1,1);
>>
>> size(u)
ans =

        1   100001

>> size(N1)
ans =

   66667       1

>> size(p1)
ans =

   1   1

>> p1
p1 =  66667
```

In the loop:

```
>> i=1;
>> U1 = floor((u(i)-minu)/du) + 1;
>> U1
U1 =  1
```

That `U1` is very different from your Python attempt!

for `i=5`:

```
>> i=5;
>> u(i)
ans =  0.040000
>> minu
minu = 0
>> du
du =  0.015000
>> (u(i)-minu)/du
ans =  2.6667
>> floor((u(i)-minu)/du) + 1
ans =  3
```

MATLAB floor does create an integer, which is fine for indexing.

```
>> floor((u(1:10)-minu)/du) + 1
ans =

   1   1   2   3   3   4   5   5   6   7
```

Comment: @hpauj not to be condescending myself but the solution was 

for i in range(0, len((u))):
    U1 = int(np.floor( (u[i] - minu) / du  ) )
    N1[int(U1)] = int(N1[U1] + 1)